# Flutter scan qr code with zoom in and zoom out options

Tags: flutter, qr-code, barcode-scanner

i am using these scan libraries and these are working good but no option for camera zoom

[barcode_scan:](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan)

[majascan:](https://pub.dev/packages/majascan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a look at the barcode_scan library you've mentioned, and their GitHub repository does show that they've added zoom capabilities in their project on the 23rd of March 2020... [Check this out](https://github.com/flutterone/flutter_barcode_reader/commit/73592b191a47b505148ef938a0e06b89f143bc91)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Flutter plugin to scan barcode and qrcode with pinch to zoom functionality using google mobile vision in android and AVfoundation in iOS.

Here is the link

https://pub.dev/packages/mvbarcodescan/

Here is the source code of the project if you want to add new features.

https://prathap_kumar@bitbucket.org/prathap_kumar/mvbarcodescan/src/master/